# Is it possible to fake Cassandra connection?

Tags: cassandra

I have been given a task to configure Cassandra DB for the project. We are facing a problem - for all environments there is a dedicated server for Cassandra. But, for the DEV environment, the client does not want to provide a seperate server and current DEV servers are already fully packaged and we can't afford to install Cassandra on them.

My question is, is there any possibility to fake connection to Cassandra in an environment? I've created CassandraConfiguration.java class, configured session, cluster etc etc, it all works smoothly on other envs, but on DEV, well, it fails, as it cannot connect, because there's no Cassandra... Commiting the cassandraconfiguration file will kill the dev.

Comment: You can mock connection class, for example with Mockito framework. Otherwise you will need to create a mock server with TCP/IP which is complex task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [scassandra](https://github.com/scassandra/scassandra-server) (simulated cassandra), or [Simulacron](https://github.com/datastax/simulacron) that are emulating Cassandra. Or you can use [cassandra-unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit) that will run Cassandra in the same JVM as your test.